# How to combine the results of two HQL queries into one

Tags: hibernate, hql

I have two HQL queries that I need to combine into a single set of results.

Both ObjectOne and ObjectTwo are derived from the same base class.  ObjectOne has

The first query is...

```
SELECT
    //Some things
FROM 

ObjectOne objectOne,
ObjectTwo objectTwo

WHERE
objectOne in elements(objectTwo.components)
```

And the second query is...

```
SELECT
    //Some things
FROM 

ObjectOne objectOne
LEFT OUTER JOIN objectOne.parentObject parentObj
WHERE parentObj.myField is null
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Union is not supported in HQL .  If you want union you should use mysql or run two separate query and combine the two results

Comment: Yep - except in this case I have to use HQL

Comment: Then I think you have to run two separate queries and append the results .